# * is displayed as ⋅ in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout

The <kbd>*</kbd> on the numpad is being displayed as <kbd>⋅</kbd> (Unicode U+22C5 DOT OPERATOR). This is also happening with the decimal <kbd>.</kbd> in numpad, which is being displayed as comma <kbd>,</kbd>.

I think I've messed up with unity tweaks settings but I tried changing some stuff but can't figure it out. Anyone came across the same problem?

Comment: what is your keyboard layout ?

Comment: @RoVo layout is English (US)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Setup** you can choose under **Region & Language** your desired config and keyboard layout.